# run multiple instances of sparkling water on the same cluster

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

Two concurrent h2ocontext created on the same driver seem to conflict with each other. When one is running, the other one will throw errors. Can we do some configuration such that two instances of sparkling water can run in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the following arguments on the command line:

`--conf spark.ext.h2o.client.port.base=26000
--conf spark.ext.h2o.node.port.base=26005`

Answer (score 0):

Sparkling Water is tight to Spark cluster. If you want to be able to run multiple Sparkling Water clusters(H2OContext), then you need to create multiple separated Spark Clusters first